# Does <input type="file"> open File Explorer by itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file

Does the input type "file" open file explorer by itself? Or is jquery/javascript needed to open the File Explorer dialog? If so can anyone give me any tips and tricks of how to do that?

Thank you for helping!

Edit: At first i thought it was Team Viewer not letting me open the file explorer using input type "file" as it worked on my desktop PC and not in team viewer. But it turns out it's the laptop that has a problem opening it, and not Team Viewer. Is there any configuration in the browser that I have to allow or something like that?

Comment: The browser controls it. JS alone cannot be used to open the file dialog.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Okay, now this is interesting, because my input type="file" doesn't open my file explorer, nothing happens when i press the Choose File button. I'm using google chrome if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: It sounds like you have an issue elsewhere then, as this is low-level behaviour

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeah, it was "team viewer" saying no to that.

Comment: `it was "team viewer" saying no to that` What does mean?

Comment: So following your edit, this is obviously a team viewer issue...

Comment: @DrCox Looks like a config issue on team viewer

Comment: @A.Wolff turns out it's my laptop that's the issue, not team viewers fault, it just wont open on my laptop for some reason. If you have any thoughts of how to fix this, please help me!

Comment: @DrCox The first thing to try is if you have same issue on different browser. And of course, disable any other running program/plugin that could affect this behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a try :

```html
Does <input type="file"> open File Explorer by itself?
```

**Note** : your quotes are not the good ones, use `"` instead of `“` and `”`

Comment: I've added a note about your quotes if it is still relevant

Comment: Accepted answer, but do you still have an issue on your laptop ? If yes can you tell me what OS and browser you are using ? (with browser version)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be considered a native element. However to substitute the input with an image/another button etc will require javascript and triggering click the hidden file input. Note that you cannot be trigger click the file input without originating from a real user click.

Not possible:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type=file]").trigger("click");
});
```

Possible:

```
$("#button1").on("click", function(){
    $("input[type=file]").trigger("click");
});
```